# Getting MongoDB current collection name

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, nosql

I am using mongoDB + Java+SpringData.
Is it possible to get current collection, without it's name?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by getting the current collection?  You can can multiple collections... If you want to just find the names of all your collections, you can go to the mongoDB prompt (mongo your_database_name), and then ask for a list of the collections: db.getCollectionNames()

Comment: I dont use command prompt in Java. I use Spring data. I dont want to have deal with "hard code " names. It looks bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is my solution(Java +SpringData).

```
@Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;    
DBCollection collection = mongoTemplate.getCollection(mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(MyDocument.class)));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to interact with the `DBCollection` directly you should rather do so through the `CollectionCallback<T>` interface and use it like this:

```
mongoTemplate.execute(new CollectionCallback<Void>() {
  public Void doInCollection(DBCollection collection) throws MongoException {
    // Implement your code here
  }
});
```

Using the callback has the advantage that you get the `MongoException`s potentially being thrown from your own code being converted into Spring's `DataAccessException` hierarchy.